# Non-persisted computed BIT column as NOT NULL?

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a computed `BIT column to my table, but I'm having a hard time understanding why SQL won't see it as NOT NULL. Am I doing something wrong, or is this not possible?

For example, take this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    SomeDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DateIsInPastInt AS CASE WHEN SomeDate < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    DateIsInPastBit AS CAST(CASE WHEN SomeDate < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT),
)
```

For both columns `DateIsInPastInt` and `DateIsInPastBit`, it's not logically possible for either of these columns to ever be `NULL`. However, SQL defines `DateIsInPastBit` as nullable:

[image]

Am I missing something, or is this just not possible with non-persisted computed `BIT` columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a total hack, but it seems to work.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    SomeDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DateIsInPastInt AS CASE WHEN SomeDate < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    DateIsInPastBit AS isnull(cast(
       CASE WHEN SomeDate < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit
    ), 1)
)
```

That said, I'm interested to know why it doesn't seem to think that the `cast` itself will unequivocally return a value. And, if by doing the hack above, we're avoiding some weird case and potentially a bug.

Comment: Yes, this does indeed work! I actually tried a similar approach, but putting the `ISNULL` check inside the `CAST`, but that still didn't work. For some reason, I was thinking I needed the `CAST` on the outside for the type to get recognized. Thanks!